# Field for Getting Page Status Comment Like Data with Page/Feed Request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When making a request with facebook's graph api as follows:

`{page-id}/feed?fields=myfield1,myfield2,etc`

Is there a way to request additional data for comments that are made on statuses for that `{page-id}`?

For Example, when making the call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{page-id}/feed?field=comments?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx`

The following data (only relevant snippet) is returned:

```
comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "created_time": "2016-11-24T01:xx:xx+0000",
            "from": {
              "name": "jane doe",
              "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "message": "I am what I type.",
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
```

I've noticed that in the earlier versions of the graph api (v2.3 & lower) if you make the call

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{page-id}/statuses?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx`

The Following data (only relevant snippet) is available:

```
comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "created_time": "2016-11-11T13:xx:xx+0000",
            "from": {
              "name": "Jane Doe",
              "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "message": "I am what I type",
            "can_remove": false,
            "like_count": 2,
            "user_likes": false,
            "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
```

Notice the `"like_count": 2` data that is available in the second example. It provides information regarding the amount of likes that a pages' posts' comments are receiving, which seems valuable to gauge overall page engagement.

Is there a way to request this field with current versions of the api, such as v2.8?

I am very new to working with the graph API, but have noticed that the documentation is a little light on some approaches to specify data.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is `{like_count}` which can be added directly the `comment` field as such:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{page-id}/feed?field=comments{like_count}?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx`

A more 'wheels down' example:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{page-id}/feed?field=comments.limit(3).summary(true){like_count}?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx`